# Creating intermediate slices in a 3D MRI volume with MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, multidimensional-array, interpolation

I have 9 MRI images and would like to make a 3D volume out of these images.  From there, I would like to interpolate in between each slice.  Given two slices in the volume, I would like to create an intermediate frame in between that interpolates between the two slices.  The goal is to create an 18 MRI volume that performs this interpolation.

How would I accomplish this in MATLAB?

Comment: What? What do you mean by "interpolation" of the two images?... do you mean **mixing** them together?

Comment: I have to create a new image using these two, for example if I have 9 MRI images my aim is to make it 18 by interpolation, a third image should be stacked between the two, the third image should automatically fill the space between two

Comment: Yeah... that wasn't very obvious in your original problem statement.  Please update it with more details.  Are these MRI images stacked into a 3D volume?  If it is, you can simply just use `interp3`.

Comment: i want to generate a code to create that third middle image

Comment: Don't tell me.  Update your problem statement.  Are these images in a 3D volume, or are they 9 separate 2D images?

Comment: they are 9 separate 2D images

Comment: Yuck.  If you want to deal with MRI **volumes**, you need to stack them into a 3D matrix.  I've written an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that your MRI images are in a 3D stacked volume, you can accomplish what you want by using [`interp3`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp3.html).  The rows and columns of a slice will stay the same when choosing the sampling points, but the temporal or `Z` direction will simply double in size.  So something like this, assuming that `MRI` is your volume:

```
[rows,cols,slices] = size(MRI);
[X,Y,Z] = meshgrid(1:cols, 1:rows, 1:slices);
[X2,Y2,Z2] = meshgrid(1:cols, 1:rows, 0.5:0.5:slices);
out = interp3(X, Y, Z, MRI, X2, Y2, Z2, 'linear', 0);
```

The above will generate a volume that has twice as many slices, keeping the rows and columns the same and using bilinear interpolation.  The extra `0` ensures that if we are creating values that are outside of the original sampling points, we will extrapolate these points to 0.

If your images are **not** a 3D volume, you'll need to place this into a 3D matrix.  Assuming that they're called `MRI1` up to `MRI9`, you can do:

```
MRI = cat(3, MRI1, MRI2, MRI3, MRI4, MRI5, MRI6, MRI7, MRI8, MRI9);
```

You can then use the above code.  Once you're finished, you can grab the intermediate slices by doing:

```
final_slices = MRI(:,:,1:2:end);
```

You can then access each intermediate slice with `final_slices`.

---

As a quick example seeing this working, let's assume that our volume is a bunch of random numbers in a 3 x 3 x 3 volume:

```
rng(123123);
MRI = rand(3,3,3)

MRI(:,:,1) =

    0.3002    0.8302    0.1768
    0.9946    0.7214    0.0678
    0.2901    0.4627    0.5201


MRI(:,:,2) =

    0.2323    0.8516    0.7838
    0.3251    0.5326    0.6377
    0.7220    0.4735    0.0717


MRI(:,:,3) =

    0.3202    0.1259    0.3360
    0.1004    0.9260    0.6287
    0.6922    0.3191    0.9011
```

Running the above interpolation code, we get:

```
out(:,:,1) =

     0     0     0
     0     0     0
     0     0     0


out(:,:,2) =

    0.3002    0.8302    0.1768
    0.9946    0.7214    0.0678
    0.2901    0.4627    0.5201


out(:,:,3) =

    0.2662    0.8409    0.4803
    0.6598    0.6270    0.3527
    0.5060    0.4681    0.2959


out(:,:,4) =

    0.2323    0.8516    0.7838
    0.3251    0.5326    0.6377
    0.7220    0.4735    0.0717


out(:,:,5) =

    0.2763    0.4887    0.5599
    0.2127    0.7293    0.6332
    0.7071    0.3963    0.4864


out(:,:,6) =

    0.3202    0.1259    0.3360
    0.1004    0.9260    0.6287
    0.6922    0.3191    0.9011
```

As you can see, the code certainly does create intermediate slices correctly.  You see that every even position is one of the original MRI images, while the odd positions are the interpolated results.  The first slice doesn't mean anything as we are trying to extrapolate from outside the known volume.  You probably want to concentrate on the third slice and its odd positions after this point up until the end of the new volume.

Comment: thank you rayryeng,thanks alot I just hope it works

Comment: @beautifuleyez - No problem.  Let me know if it does then get back to me.  Thanks for accepting my answer btw!

Comment: I want to do 3D reconstruction of the brain tumor, uptill now I have found their boundaries and stacked them together on a 3D axis, I want to create a 3D volume of the whole using marching cubes algorithm.. can u guide me on this too

Comment: @beautifuleyez - I'm not familiar with the Marching Cubes algorithm.  I don't know much about computer graphics unfortunately :(.  However, for this particular interpolation, I know it works.  I've updated my answer to show some example results.

Comment: thanks, but what other options do I have for 3D reconstruction of brain tumor using 2D MRI slices other than interpolation

Comment: @beautifuleyez - I unfortunately have no answer for you here.  I'm not an expert in medical image processing.  I certainly am an expert in image processing, but I have no medical background or expertise - only a basic familarity.  I'm outside of my element here :(.  Apologies again.  Good luck though.

Comment: @beautifuleyez I think it's best if you ask a new question about that. Make sure it is specific and detailed enough. An [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be good.

Comment: @rayryeng this code has some issue with out = interp3(X, Y, Z, MRI, X2, Y2, Z2, 'linear', 0);

Comment: please help me with that asap

Comment: Uh... yeah. Sure. *What* issue?  I'm certainly not a mindreader, nor am I clairvoyant.  If it's my job to guess what's wrong, I'm not playing this game.

Comment: @LuisMendo - Mentalist.

Comment: Im getting an error in it.. can u modify it,, or change it.. such that it works

Comment: Yeah **what error**?  If you followed what I did above in my answer, you should be able to get it working. I even show an example of it working. Until you actually tell me what's wrong and what the error is, our conversation stops here.